# NetBeans stuck on 2nd screen that doesn't exist

Tags: netbeans, windows-7, multiple-monitors

I'm running NetBeans 8 on Windows 7, and I had a problem when using my laptop away from my docking station, where it positions the IDE window on what would be a 2nd screen, and there is no way to move it into the laptop screen.

If I go back to my docking station, where I have a 2nd monitor, I can drag it back onto the 1st screen fine, but otherwise it looks like I am out of luck... is there any way to fix this if I'm not plugged into a 2nd monitor?

Comment: Ok, I use linux but if i recall, you can right click on the app in the taskbar, choose move and with the arrow keys move the window.

Comment: huh I'll try that...

Comment: this bug is already 10 years old and still a problem even in netbeans 8.2 https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=121245

Answer (score 3):

You can move the window back on the screen using the following procedure without closing NetBeans or deleting any files.

1. Give the offscreen NetBeans window focus using Alt-Tab or clicking it in the task bar.
2. Press `Alt-Space`, then `m`, then `left arrow` key
3. Move your mouse until the window is visible.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me often and I resolve it as follows:

1. Close NetBeans if it's open.
2. Open the file WindowManager.wswmgr. On my system (Windows 10, NetBeans 12.5), this is located in `C:/Users/ <MyUserName>/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/12.5/config/Windows2Local/WindowManager.wswmgr`.
3. In the element `<joined-properties>` nested under `<windowmanager> <main-window>`, edit the x and y attributes to small non-negative values, for example 0 or 100. This sets the top left position of the main Netbeans window.
4. Save the file, then reopen Netbeans
   This happens often enough that I have a shortcut on my desktop to this file.

Comment: Never mind, Corey's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same issue by going to System -> Display -> Scale & layout and then changing the Scale from 100% to 175% and then gradually brough it to back to 100%